# Flutter Text(str) isn't updating

Tags: flutter, dart

i try to update text in the Text() but for some reason it doesn't update and i can't figure out why. i believe it should update after i leave note_page, tho it doesn't.

```
List<String> Titles = [];

List<Widget> active_notes = [];



  Widget W1(BuildContext context) {
    final key = ValueKey(DateTime.now().toString());
    int index = -1;
    int ind = Titles.length - 1;
    Titles[Titles.length - 1] = "title" + ind.toString();
    return TextButton(
      key: key,
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          index = active_notes.indexWhere((e) => e.key == key);
          print("index: $index");
          Titles[index] = "title" + index.toString();
          return noteScreenState.note_page(
              context, index); //calling the editing menu
        })).then((_) {
          setState(() {
            Titles[index] = "Title" + index.toString();
          });
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 50,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Text(
              Titles[ind], 
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 22,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

could anyone help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: need more info. does your `active_notes` have value ?  what does `print("index: $index");` prints ? any screen shot of what you are expecting and what happening will be helpfull